# Find soft hyphens in HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, soft-hyphen

Let's look at following code:

```
$('#el').html('ex&shy;am&shy;ple');
```

Now, how can I get back that element's text with soft hyphens entities?
Both of these:

```
$('#el').html();
$('#el').contents().get(0).nodeValue;
```

gives me "example" as return value, not "ex&shy;am&shy;ple"

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/w7QKH/

Browser: FF7, not checked in other browsers.

Comment: in b4 `$('#el').html('ex<wbr>am<wbr>ple');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually $('#el').html() gives you `'example'` with soft hyphens. If you run $('#el').html().length it will return 9. So hyphens are in, but they are not displayed. And it is not equal `'ex&shy;am&shy;ple'` , because this string is not escaped. If you want to compare to string you should use `'ex\u00ADam\u00ADple'`- here I replaced `&shy;` with its unicode value. http://jsfiddle.net/w7QKH/1/

Comment: Big ups! Been pulling my hair here! <3

Answer (score 1):

`$('#el').html().replace(/\u00AD/g, '&shy;');`

See http://jsfiddle.net/K9mUy/